# Estimating number of types of things, from many observations

Tags: estimation, sampling, exchangeability

I go on a safari.  Each day, I see various animals, and a keep track of all of my observations.  Assume that each time I make an observation I see a single animal.  At one point, I've made a total of 153 observations and I've seen 127 rabbits, 22 gazelle, 3 lions, and 1 tiger (4 different species).  This makes me curious: what is the probability that the next animal I observe will be from a new species, i.e., not one of the 4 I've already seen?

Is there a way to get an estimate or bound on this probability?  If not, is there a pragmatic way to get an estimate, perhaps making some additional assumptions that might potentially be reasonable in practice?

---

<sub>I'm not trying to estimate the total number of species, but just that the next observation is from a species I haven't seen yet.  I feel like I might have read about this problem somewhere in a paper long ago, but I can't remember the details -- and now I've run across a practical situation where I need to solve it.  It feels like it ought to be possible to make some deduction by applying exchangeability, but I can't manage to make the details work out.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in this area, but I understand that both 
[The Indian Buffet Process](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v12/griffiths11a.html) and [The Chinese Restaurant Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process) specifically address this question.

Comment: Cool, that looks relevant!  So if we knew that the process was a Chinese Restaurant Process with parameter $\theta$ (and discount $\alpha=0$), then the probability that the next observation is from a new species would be $1/(153+\theta)$.  But we're not given $\theta$, so I guess that's something we need to estimate from the data.   Question: If we assume that the observations follow a CRP with (unknown) $\theta$, given the 153 observations so far, how should we estimate the (posterior) for $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, you need to estimate those, but I am not the one to advise you how.

Comment: OK, thank you for the pointer to relevant material!  Small correction: the $1/(153+\theta)$ above was a typo and should have been $\theta/(153+\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each observation is independent, then maybe we can model this using Bernoulli. The Bayesian approach would be that,
Let $X$ be number of observation that doesn't belong to the 4 species you mentioned. Assume that, $$X \sim Bin(n,p)$$
$$p_{prior} \sim Beta(1, 1)$$
prior distribution of p is uniform here, i.e. any probability is equally possible. Then posterior probability of $p$ would be
$$p_{posterior} \sim Beta(1+n_{success}\ , 1+n_{failure})$$
In your case posterior p has distribution of $Beta(1, 154)$. Expectation of probability of seeing a "new species" in the next observation should be $1/155$. And if you failed to observe a new species in your next observation, you can update this distribution to $Beta(1, 155)$ and the expectation of this distribution becomes $1/156$.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but I don't think it can be right.  The final answer you got is completely independent of the observations: it doesn't matter how many species we've seen so far (or how many times we've seen each species), and the answer depends only on $n$, the number of observations.  If I had seen a total of 1 species so far, the answer would be $1/155$; and if I had 100 species so far, the answer would still be $1/155$.  That can't be right.  I think the problem is that the definition of $X$ isn't defined in advance before seeing the data.